# Angular 9 (Ivy): CSS class^ attribute selectors stops working with angular material components

Tags: angular, angular-material, css-selectors, angular9, angular-ivy

I am currently updating an Angular project from v8 to v9, and I have discovered an issue with using CSS class attributes together with Angular Material components.
I have also updated to Material v9.

With this simplified HTML,

```js
// Example List 1
<mat-nav-list class="example-list-1">
  <mat-list-item> SOME HTML.. </mat-list-item>
</mat-nav-list>

// Example List 2
<div class="example-list-2">
  <mat-list-item> SOME HTML.. </mat-list-item>
</div>
```

the following SCSS,

```css
[class^="example-list"] {
  mat-list-item {
    SOME SCSS..
  }
}
```

is only adding style to the `<mat-list-item>` in **Example List 2**, where `<div>` is being used.

It works fine if I, for example, use **id** instead of **class** in both HTML and SCSS, but I would prefer not to have to do a lot of tinkering with the code.

**Update**

I have also found out it works fine if I disable Ivy.

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
 }
```

Why is it not working with Ivy? Is this expected behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you faced a bug that was introduced with Ivy https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/33111

The issue here is the wrong order of adding css classes.

`MatNavList` component has a `host` property binding within metadata:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'mat-nav-list',
  host: {
    'role': 'navigation',
    'class': 'mat-nav-list mat-list-base',
  },
  ...
})
export class MatNavList
```

https://github.com/angular/components/blob/74685883ec16782d172a4505348eef6f2003a31b/src/material/list/list.ts#L66

Before Ivy your class was added first to class attribute of element:

```
<mat-nav-list class="example-list-1 mat-nav-list mat-list-base"
```

with early Ivy version it became the last added class:

```
<mat-nav-list class="mat-nav-list mat-list-base example-list-1"
```

As a result your selector doesnt work for second case. But there is an alternative:

```
[class*="example-list"] {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Spot on! Thanks a lot. Do you happen to know if this changes in newer versions? I'm planning to take our project all the way to v13, and it would be nice not having to change the code..

Comment: I just tested it with ng13.0.0. The behavior remained the same as in early Ivy releases ng9